# Howto throw Exceptions in Admin subscribed events?

Tags: payment, shopware6

I have a shopware6 payment provider plugin.
In this i have two subscribed events in my plugin for admin hooks for processing credit and capturing to the api of the payment provider.

```
OrderEvents::ORDER_LINE_ITEM_WRITTEN_EVENT => 'lineItemWritten',
StateMachineTransitionEvent::class => 'onStateTransition'
```

In one i will send a credit to the payment platform.
In another i will capture an amount if the payment method was captured manual before.

Everything works fine, i call the api of the provider, got feedback, everything fine there.
But the only problem is, when i receive a "Failed" from the payment provider API (no matter what the reason is, its not important, could be different errors, thats not the problem) i want to show an error message in the shopware backend. like when something is saved, then there is a "Saved" notification in the top right corner. I want that too, but with an error and a detailed message.

I tried to throw exceptions, but that does not change anything. Nothing really happens, when i throw exceptions, shopware just ignores it.

As example: When the amount is captured twice (which can be reproduced easily in shopware) sthere is an error of "Amount override", which is correct. But when this is so, i want to go back to payment status "open" (which already works) AND i want to throw an error message.

Currently simply no message is shown.sds
I tried to manipulate the header, but then i just output common messages like "Request failed with status code 400" (or 500).

I want to output the exact error or at least something like "order can not be captured".

Here is (a part) of the shopware6 subscriber class

```
namespace Example\Plugin\Subscriber;

... // uses

class OrderPlacedEventSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {
   ...

    public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
        return [
            PreWriteValidationEvent::class => 'validateStateChange'
        ];
    }

    public function validateStateChange(PreWriteValidationEvent $event) {
        $writeCommands = $event->getCommands();

        foreach ($writeCommands as $index => $command) {
            $payload = $command->getPayload();
            $actionName = $payload["action_name"] ?? "";

            if($actionName == "paid") {
                $entityIdDetails = json_decode($payload["entity_id"]);
                $transactionId = $entityIdDetails->id;

                $criteria = new Criteria();
                $criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter("id", $transactionId));
                $criteria->addAssociation("order");
                $criteria->addAssociation("paymentMethod");
                $criteria->addAssociation('order.lineItems');
                $criteria->addAssociation("order.currency");

   
                /** @var OrderTransactionEntity $transaction */
                $transaction = $this->transactionRepository->search($criteria, $event->getContext())->first();

                if(is_null($transaction)) {
                    return;
                }

                $order = $transaction->getOrder();

                try {
                    /** @var PaymentMethodEntity $paymentMethod */
                    $paymentMethod = $transaction->getPaymentMethod();
                    $identifier = $paymentMethod->getHandlerIdentifier();

                    if($identifier == Creditcard::class || $identifier == Paypal::class) {
                        $result = Order::captureNow($order);

                        if(!$result["status"]) {
                            // NOT WORKING
                            $event->getExceptions()->add(new FailedCaptureException($result["response"]["Description"]));
                        } else {
                            // successful things
                        }
                    }
                } catch(\Exception $e) {
                    // NOT WORKING
                    $event->getExceptions()->add(new FailedCaptureException($e->getMessage()));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here also the Custom Exception

```
<?php

namespace Example\Plugin\Helper\Exceptions;

use Shopware\Core\Framework\ShopwareHttpException;

class FailedCaptureException extends ShopwareHttpException {

    public function __construct(string $message, array $parameters = []) {
        parent::__construct($message, $parameters);
    }

    public function getErrorCode(): string {
        return 'EXAMPLE__FAILED_CAPTURE';
    }

    public function getStatusCode(): int {
        return 400;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php

namespace MyPlugin\Exception;

use Shopware\Core\Framework\ShopwareHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class MyCustomShopwareException extends ShopwareHttpException
{
    public function __construct(string $message, array $parameters = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($message, $parameters);
    }

    public function getErrorCode(): string
    {
        return 'MY_PLUGIN_CUSTOM_ERROR';
    }

    public function getStatusCode(): int
    {
        return Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST;
    }

}
```

In EventSubscriberInterface

```
throw new EntryException('Error message');
```

Comment: Lukas, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Will try that out later, thanks. Maybe a custom exception helps. But like written in my question throwing exceptions did not do a single thing. But let cross fingers, maybe this helps

Comment: For StateMachineTransitionEvent You must use PreWriteValidationEvent

Comment: Exception did not help like i thought. I will now try out the PreWriteValidationEvent

Comment: So i now tried that out, too. I also found different examples of this in the shopware core which also use custom exceptions. So i built that too. It also seem to work. In the plugin i do 

$event->getExceptions()->add(new FailedCaptureException($e->getMessage()));

But sadly i just again get a 400 error in the frontend. All other scripts from shopware which throw exceptions like me are not hooking into transaction state, but shipment and other different things. Maybe its just not working for transaction states?

Comment: Show me the entire code

Comment: I have posted the code

Comment: you didn't use anywhere in the code

`throw new FailedCaptureException('Error message');`

you have to throw an error for it to go further

Comment: I tried both. Throwing it and adding it. But i will give it a shot again tomorrow.